# Populate a Column in Google sheet using another date column

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a date in Column F which is populated by google forms. I have another date column K which is blank and needs to get populated from the date from Column F as DD/MM format.
This needs to run on every edit made in the sheet. On every edit, all the data needs to be checked in Col F from row 1 and necessary population to be done in K.

I have tried with this script but to no avail.
Please help be get this working

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  //var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Form responses 1'); // Replace 'YourSheetName' with the name of your sheet
  var range = e.range;
  // Check if the edited cell is in Column F
  if (range.getColumn() == 6) { // Column F is the 6th column
    var dateValue = range.getValue();
    
    // Check if the edited cell has a valid date
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(dateValue) === "[object Date]" && !isNaN(dateValue)) {
      // Format the date as DD/MM
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateValue), 'Asia/Calcutta', 'dd/MM');
      
      // Update the corresponding cell in Column K
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 11).setValue(formattedDate);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do that with an onFormSubmit trigger and use Utilities.formatDate().

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the onFormSubmit trigger.  You can create one with the triggers menu in the editor. Just name the trigger handler function the same name as this function.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getRange();
  let dt = new Date(e.values[6]);//the value that would go in col 7
  sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,11).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(dt,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"dd/MM"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I also add manual inputs in the sheets with the form input and wish the script to work in all cases. So what changes would be necessary to the solution you provided?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. There is nothing in the question about other fields

Comment: Your solution will trigger in case of an entry submitted through a form.
I also add data to this sheet manually at times. Will your solution also trigger when manual data is entered?

Comment: No it will not trigger user edits. You will need to use an all edit trigger to do that.. but keep in mind that on edit triggers do not trigger on the script actions for formula, actions